# Heroku: Deploying rails application troubles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, hosting, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my rails application with heroku (as shown [here](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/)). I've created a very simple rails application (using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.3; i'm sure heroku supports these - see heroku docs), created and pushed github repo, created heroku repo and pushed it (all commiting is done). And when i'm trying to access my application controller, it throws 404 rails page like it's saying 'there is no such controller'. I've done `heroku rake db:migrate` but first time i ran it i got 'host not found' error. Running this again fixed that. Well, i'm not sure if i should run `heroku addons add:postgresql` - i though postgres is on by default, but heroku says i should pay in order to get DB (running command i've mentioned asks me to confirm billing it).

May be it sounds stupid, but how can i deploy my rails application (it's a very simple one) without paying any fees and such troubles as 404 pages like i mentioned in the beginning of my post? (and this is my question). Maybe i should choose other hosting (if it exists in our world) or am i doing something wrong with heroku?

Comment: Yeah, sure. And when i'm trying to see my controller locally it showss as-must-be while heroku throws 404s.

Comment: did you push all your files? Can you show us the error?

Comment: yes. except docs, swaps and other set in .gitignore. you can see it on github: https://github.com/shybovycha/discord

Comment: As said in my answer below, you forgot to push some files =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to push your `quotes_controller.rb` to git and heroku probably.

```
git add controllers/quotes_controller.rb
```

it seems you forgot models also, and probably lot of files.

Comment: damn it... yeah, thanks! i've spent nearly 4 or more hrs searching for errors and seems that the main error was my git using ineptitude =P

Comment: You can cheat and use `git add .` to add any files that aren't already tracked, in future. It'll save you the hassle, and it will (of course) still abide by your .gitignore file.

Comment: i'm using `git commit -a` instead of `git add . && git commit`

Comment: rails new yourapp > git init > git add .     is fine. After that git add yourfiles and git commit or git commit -a is fine too.